# Eclipse RCP or SWT/JFace demo or "examples with code"?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I learned the little I know of wxPython (as in: Python wrappers for wx widgets) from the absolutely **outstanding** demo app: http://wxpython.org/download.php

With that demo app, you get examples for many, many uses of the framework widgets: both code and running UI frames. It is absolutely amazing just how well that is done.

Is there anything even remotely close to that for Eclipse RCP or SWT/JFace?

I have to "port" a concept I developed in wx over to Java.. and I am not sure Swing would cut it. Eclipse RCP or SWT/JFace look extremely good but.. where's the material to help me get started? I Googled but I couldn't find anywhere something that I could download and run.. and see the code behind it!

Note: I could of course "download and run" Eclipse itself.. but that's way more complex that I can probably manage at the moment. There's the brilliance of wx demos: they are even gradual in complexity!

Comment: if you think the question is answered, please mark it as answered ;)

Comment: Ok, @aphex I will. To be honest, what I found in your links (and BTW, thanks again for them) is still not quite there yet when compared with the wxPython demo app. I could accept for now and switch answers later if anybody comes up with a more comprehensive one. (BTW: I also looked at the provided Snippets..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with the [vogella website](http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html). There you can find all you need to start with. As Alexey Romanov mentioned, the RCP Mail Template is also a really good example, but I'm not sure if Eclipse 4.x is used, but I doubt. So start learning the 4.x platform.

For SWT there is a [Demo application](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php) showing all the components.For JFaces I also recommend you the [JFace Snippets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets).

Answer (score 0):

The canonical example is the [RCP Mail Template](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-RCP-3/tutorial3.html) ([version 2.0](http://max-server.myftp.org/trac/rcp-mail)). There are more examples listed [here](http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/eclipsercp/rcp_examples/) and [JFace Snippets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets).